# Problema con asincronía NODEJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs

estoy intentando llamar a una función desde una clase de JS, dicha función debería retornar un token de acceso, pero en vez de eso, devuelve "Undefined", alguien puede saber por qué pasa?

```
// Función que devuelve el token...

const request = require("request");
const clc = require('cli-color');
const config = require('./config.js');

const getBearer = () => {

    const formData = {
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        client_id: `${config.UID}`,
        client_secret: `${config.SECRET}`,
    }

    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://api.intra.42.fr/oauth/token",
        headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data", },
        formData: formData
    }

    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(clc.red(`Error: ${error}`));
        }
        else {
            const parsed = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(parsed.access_token); // Muestra el token correctamente
            return (parsed.access_token);
        }
    });
}

module.exports = { getBearer }
```

```
// Llamada a la función desde la clase ...

    init() {
        app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, this.srcsPath)));
        app.listen(this.port, () => { console.debug(clc.cyan(`Debug: Server listening on port ${this.port}`)) });
        this._connectApi();
    }

    async _connectApi() {
        try {
            let token = await getBearer();
            console.log(token); // Muestra undefined
        } catch(e) {
            console.error(clc.red(e));
        }
    }
```

El problema es en la parte de (REQUEST), estoy retornando el valor desde dentro de la función, pero luego getBearer no retorna nada, pero no sé como hacer que lo devuelva correctamente.

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en que no estas esperando a la respuesta de la request, por eso no obtienes ningun valor. La libreria que estas usando para realizar las solicitudes no usa promesas y recomiendan usar otras, como indica en su [documentacion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait). De todas formas te recomendaria usar una libreria que no este en desuso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que aclarar:

1. La funcion de `getBearer()` debe ser asíncrona (la estás llamando con un `await`), por lo que debes definiarla así:
   `const getBearer = async () => {...}`
2. Si no me equivoco, la bilbioteca `request` está obsoleta por lo que te recomiendo utilizar otra. En lo personal utilizo `axios` pero escoge la que más te guste/convenga.
3. Al hacer el llamado http con la biblioteca, debes devolver una promesa o esperar por la respuesta con un `await`. En tu caso particular, la respuesta http se te devuelve en un callback así que debes construir una promesa y retornarla. Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```js
const getBearer = async () => {
  /** formData y request options **/

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if(error) reject(error);

      const parsed = JSON.parse(body);
      resolve(parsed.access_token);
    });
  });
}
```

De esta manera, ya no te devolverá `undefined`. Pero repito, yo considero que deberías utilizar otra biblioteca que no sea `request`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he cambiado a Axios y lo he hecho todo diferente y más sencillo <3

Comment: Genial @abello-r :D!!